# Why choosing for an Object Parser instead of an Array Parser

Tags: arrays, object, xml-parsing

I'm parsing a XML-file into objects but I'm wondering why,
I would haven't choosed an Array Parser instead of an Object Parser?

Does it have more pro's than an Array parser or less contra's?
is it more flexible and expansible?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I think it all depends on the input data. If you application needs a lot of simple configuration files storing the state/setup of a single object, then there would be less overhead in handling the parser's output if you use ObjectParser.

But once you have a scenario when you need to store actual object collections (e.g., a list of independent GUI controls to be attached somewhere) and you read such collections often enough, then, if you still use ObjectParser you would have to invent a "collection" class and convert this list to the actual array.